# IIS Client Authentication without a CDP

Tags: c#, certificate, iis-7.5, x509

I'm running IIS 7.5 on Win2k8, and am trying to configure 2-way SSL.  I've turned Require Client Certificate on in IIS, I've installed a valid root certificate in my local machine's trusted root store, and I've installed the server cert and configured IIS to use it.

When I first tested this configuration, I was able to connect with a valid cert, and unable to connect with an untrusted cert.  So far so good.  However, when I revoked a user cert, that user was still able to gain access to the website using the revoked certificate.
I read that the server may have been using a cached copy of the CRL, so I used "certutil -setreg chain\ChainCacheResyncFiletime @now" to clear the cache, reimported my CRL into the Intermediate Certificate Authority store, and tried again.  This time, the server rejected ALL attempts to connect, including those with valid certs, returning 403.13 and "The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline."

My setup is a little unusual because the CA server is not available to my network, so there is no OCSP and no CDP.  Instead, I manually import the CRL to the server whenever a new one is issued, call it once a week.  So I've enabled 'Verify Client Certificate Revocation' and 'Verify Revocation Using Cached Client Certificate Only', to try to enforce checking for revocation and to prevent the server from trying to go to an unreachable CDP and thus failing the check because the server is unreachable.

Unfortunately, it looks like the server is not using the CRL I loaded into the machine store, and is instead rejecting all users because it thinks it does not have a valid CRL and cannot request a new one.

How do I get client authentication and 2-way SSL working with revocation checking when I don't have access to a CDP?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better venue. For what its worth, I think its an interesting question.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I've posted over at Server Fault, and if I find an answer, I'll try to post it here (just in case).

Comment: Well, after working with several groups, including Microsoft support, it looks like this is not possible.

If your root certificate, client certificate, or CRL contain CDP or AIA information, Windows will ALWAYS go there first to get a cached copy, before using a manually loaded CRL.

Only if your certificates and CRL all have NO CDP or AIA information at all will Windows allow you to verify using local files only.

Answer (score 0):

Don't inport CRLs to store manually. Make access to CDP :)

You could do this:
Find a server in your infrastructure that has connect to the CDP and also to your server.

Then either deploy new CRLs there and change DNS (or change hosts file on your server) to point to this server whenever windows/IIS asks for new CRL.

Or make this new server a proxy (I think it called reverse proxy) delegating requests for new CRL to correct destination at CDP.

Both solutions should work. The first mentioned could be somewhat harder to implement and maintain because you would have to monitor if the script (or person) really deploying the CRLs.